# How to start a docker container when windows boots

Tags: docker, virtualbox, boot2docker

Is there a recommended way of starting a docker container when windows boots?

I'm investigating around `vboxmanage guestcontrol` (see: http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-guestcontrol) but I'm don't figure out all of that.

Any best practice to recommend?

Regards,

Xavier

Comment: If the container is started with `--restart=always`, it should automatically start when the VirtualBox VM is started, so the challenge is then to make the VirtualBox VM start when Windows starts :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by doing this:

```
boot2docker down
boot2docker up
eval "$(boot2docker shellinit)"
docker run myImage
```